# What is YQL ? Is it like jQuery ? How can i use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

What is YQL ? Is it like jQuery ? How can i use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YQL(Yahoo query Language) helps you do select * from internet. Which means this is a SQL like query that helps you collect/join/filter/extract data from internet using simple SQL.

This is a very powerful tool atleast for me, you can easily do wonders using this.

Select * from html where url='example.com' is a small example of a major thing.

You can try this video which explains YQL to a new and basic user.
http://blog.konarkmodi.com/tag/yql

Answer (score 13):

Definition:

> The Yahoo! Query Language is an
>   expressive SQL-like language that lets
>   you query, filter, and join data
>   across Web services. With YQL, apps
>   run faster with fewer lines of code
>   and a smaller network footprint.

See more in [yahoo reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

No, it doesn't have anything with jQuery. It's like a SQL to webservices, etc.

jQuery is used to manipulate (x)HTML, handle events, handle animations, help in crossbrowsing, etc.

---

**EDIT**

YQL example:

```
select * from flickr.photos.search where text="Cat" limit 10
```

*Access Flickr website and gets photo information.*

jQuery example:

```
$(".search[text=Cat]").text();
```

*Search current page, looking everthing with class search and have attribute text = Cat. Returns his text.*

---

Comment: but how can i use yql with jqury ajax ?

Comment: The same way you use any other JSON-P based HTTP API with it. You make a request, then you parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example using YQL and jQuery to build a FAQ list:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/08/dynamic-faq-jquery-yql-google-docs/

Answer (score 0):

YQL is a simple SQL like language but end up expanding into a REST URL, which will deliver you XML or JSON data so that you can quickly create a mashup.

When its comes to YQL always follow Christian Heilmann (http://www.twitter.com/codepo8). Here is His video http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=heilmann-yql

Read this Wikipedia article that might give a little quick start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YQL_Page_Scraping (this example uses HTML table of YQL)

Page Scraping can also be done using this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bkmllkjbfbeephbldeflbnpclgfbjfmn

I am huge fan of YQL here is some more i created using YQL (pure javascript page , do a view source) http://www.purplegene.com/static/twenital.html

Google and you might find some more good examples.

here is another one from me!
http://www.purplegene.com/static/androidversions.html